# Image processor Error with umbraco and Azure blob

Tags: umbraco7, azure-blob-storage, imageprocessor

I have a serious issue with my site after change our image storage to Azure blob, when I tried to delete it I get this error list

```
2017-05-11 17:10:05,271 [P1012/D3/T40] ERROR ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule - 
ImageProcessor.Common.Exceptions.ImageProcessingException: ProcessImageAsync 597 : No image exists at D:\home\site\wwwroot\media\126812\bob400x600.jpg
 2017-05-11 17:12:17,573 [P1012/D3/T23] ERROR ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule - 
ImageProcessor.Common.Exceptions.ImageProcessingException: ProcessImageAsync 597 : No image exists at D:\home\site\wwwroot\media\126803\constance-659x420.jpg
 2017-05-11 17:14:25,462 [P1012/D3/T14] ERROR ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule - 
ImageProcessor.Common.Exceptions.ImageProcessingException: ProcessImageAsync 597 : No image exists at D:\home\site\wwwroot\media\126805\vietna.jpg
 2017-05-11 17:14:52,993 [P1012/D3/T39] ERROR ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule - 
ImageProcessor.Common.Exceptions.ImageProcessingException: ProcessImageAsync 597 : No image exists at D:\home\site\wwwroot\media\126811\cuda-659x420.jpg
 2017-05-11 17:15:19,981 [P1012/D3/T8] ERROR ImageProcessor.Web.HttpModules.ImageProcessingModule - ImageProcessor.Common.Exceptions.ImageProcessingException: ProcessImageAsync 597 : No image exists at D:\home\site\wwwroot\media\126810\where.jpg
```

This images are inside a Custom mediatype but it was working untill I move it to another folder in the website structure. Now i can do anything with it, I can't delete it, change or move it.

Could be some config errors? I really don't know why the image processor are looking into local media, because it is all on the blob.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After changed your image storage to Azure blob, the original files are still stored on your local. You can't modify both or you just can't modify the original files?

Comment: @Amor-MSFT My files where moved to the blob, I do not have any content on my media folder. This errors occurred when I try to change the images on the content, they have the path as a virtual directory on the BO like `www.mysite.com/media/126811/cuda-659x420.jpg`. The image is on the blob when i look it on `[myblobUrl]/media/126811/cuda-659x420.jpg` I don't know why this behavior and why the new created yesterday I can't modify it today. Too weird.

Comment: @Amor-MSFT I have my websites on azure, and I get this feature to store it on a blob because I'm using azure slots to make changes con the website structure. Could be this changes the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> My files where moved to the blob, I do not have any content on my media folder. This errors occurred when I try to change the images on the content, they have the path as a virtual directory on the BO like www.mysite.com/media/126811/cuda-659x420.jpg

By default the UmbracoFileSystemProviders.Azure plugin will serve files transparently from your domain or serve media directly from Azure. This is made possible by using a custom Virtual Path Provider included and automatically initialised upon application startup. You could disable it by setting useDefaultRoute configuration item which nested in FileSystemProviders to false.

```
<add key="useDefaultRoute" value="false" />
```

For more information, link below is for your reference.

[README document of UmbracoFileSystemProviders.Azure](https://github.com/JimBobSquarePants/UmbracoFileSystemProviders.Azure/blob/develop/README.md)

Comment: I don't recommend disabling it. It looks to me like you are missing the VPP web.config requirements in your media folder specified in the readme.